# How to use custom classes via "use" in Laravel's 5 blade templates?

Tags: php, linux, apache, laravel

I have a web-server on windows and Linux based server. When I'm launching Laravel 5 project on windows everything works fine, but I have a trouble with Linux (ubuntu) server and the same trouble on my hosting. When I'm trying to load the index page I'm getting an error like this:

> Class 'App\Helpers\Substr' not found

It happened because I'm using custom helpers in my blade templates and had been loading it via the "use" operator like this:

```
<?php

use App\Helpers\Substr;
use App\Helpers\LoaderBtn;

?>

@extends('zaks.public')

@section('content')

@include('zaks.search')
```

So, what might be a good solution in this situation when the project has been finished?

Comment: Use a view composer instead: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers

Comment: Thanks! View composer looks good for this project, but any way I cannot understand why in windows everything works. Is it case sensitive problem? Why?

Answer (score 13):

First, make sure your classes are autoloaded via Composer or so.

Then, you can add your namespaced classes to the `'aliases'` array in `config/app.php`, like this:

```
'aliases' => array(
   // other aliases...
   'App_Helper_Substr' => 'App\Helpers\Substr',
);
```

and then use it right in your view the regular way:

```
App_Helper_Substr->something...
App_Helper_Substr::something();
```

You can name your aliases whatever you want.

Comment: I'm trying to do it, but looks like It doesn't work for me. Maybe this solution works only with Service Provider for each custom class like
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class and 'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is that your file system on your Windows machine isn't case sensitive. Therefore, when you try to load a class like `App\Helpers\Substr`, while you actually meant `App\Helpers\SubStr`, or the file path does not correspond exactly with the class name when it comes to case (PSR-4), your class will still load on Windows.

Linux however is less forgiving, and has a filesystem that is case sensitive (at least my dev Ubuntu version does, but I guess it is the default for Linux).

So what you should do to fix this is track down your "case typo(s)" and fix it.

To prevent these issues, and catch them as soon as you make the mistake, I would strongly suggest to only develop on a case sensitive file system. I know you can make a case sensitive partition on mac, so I would guess something similar is possible somehow for Windows. Or you could work in a Linux VM like [homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) while developing. I'm a big fan of keeping your dev environment as close to the production environment as possible.