# How to call an external function inside a view in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, class, laravel-5

I want to call an external function from my blade view.

I have tried in this way,

```
{{ controllername::function name()}}
```

But i get a response like Class 'controllername' not found.

How i can solve this?Looking for a solution.

Comment: external class function or same class function in same file?

Comment: external class function in different file.

Comment: try this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578273/how-to-use-custom-classes-via-use-in-laravels-5-blade-templates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a method from one controller inside another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750913/call-a-method-from-one-controller-inside-another)

Comment: What's the version of the Laravel?

Comment: 5.2 @OmisakinOluwatobi

Comment: Thanks.Its working.@ChoncholMahmud

Answer (score 2):

If you have a function which is being used at multiple places you should define it in helpers file, to do so create one (may be) in app/Http/Helpers folder and name it helpers.php, mention this file in autorun block of your composer.json in following way :

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Http/Helpers/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

run composer dump-autoload, and then you may call this function from anywhere, let it be controller view or model.

or if you don't need to put in the helpers. You can just simply call it from it's controller. Just make it a  `static function`. Create.

```
public static function funtion_name($args) {}
```

Call.

```
\App\Http\Controllers\ControllerName::function_name($args)
```

If you don't like the very long code, you can just make it

```
ControllerName::function_name($args)
```

but don't forget to call it from the top of the view page.

```
use \App\Http\Controllers\ControllerName;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Laravel 5.5, there is a way to do that using [Service Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#service-injection). A verbatim copied example from the doc:

```
@inject('metrics', 'App\Services\MetricsService')

<div>
    Monthly Revenue: {{ $metrics->monthlyRevenue() }}.
</div>
```

If you are not Using L5.5, then you can `/Use/The/Path/OfTheClass`, so that the example above will be:

```
<div>
    Monthly Revenue: {{ \App\Services\MetricsService::monthlyRevenue() }}.
</div>
```

> Beware that, in this case `monthlyRevenue()` has to be a static function, which is sensible.

Otherwise, its much advisable to ensure the function that returns your view already did the work you need in `theFunction()` and then pass it as value to the view directly.

> Also Its hard to understand why you'll need your controller function in your view in the first place. Perhaps you need to check if your are not doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above response. Just to correct your approach.

```
//include the controller class in to your blade file.
<?php use App\Http\Controllers\MyController;?>

//call the controller function in php way.
<?php echo MyController::myFunction(); ?>

// Or call the controller function in blade way.
{{MyController::myFunction()}}
```

We first map the controller in our blade file and call controller function from view in. We just make a static function in our controller class and calling in the static function.